# Multiple If statements within Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I want to merge the condition result of my 2 If statements. First if statement result shows only both 0 result, in second if statement result one of them has to be bigger than 0... Want I want to do is Leave second condition as it is and modify first if statament like my code...

***my Code***

```
If (Inventory) <> 0 Then 
    If Apple = "" And Banana = "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND (myApple = 0 AND myBanana = 0) + (myApple <> 0 OR myBanana <> 0)"
    End If
End If
```

**//First**

```
If (Inventory) <> 0 Then 
    If Apple = "" And Banana = "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND (myApple = 0 AND myBanana = 0)"
    End If
End If
```

***First result:***

```
myApple myBanana
 0       0
 0       0
 continue...
```

**//Second**

```
If int(Inventory) <> -1 Then    
    If Apple = "" And Banana = "" Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND (myApple <> 0 OR myBanana <> 0)"
    End If
End If
```

***second result:***

```
 myApple myBanana
     0       5
     1       0
     continue...
```

***The result that I want to see:***

```
myApple myBanana
     0       0
     0       0
     0       5
     1       0
     6       0
     0       0
  continue.....
```

Comment: Why not to remove your conditions at all? Then you'll get what you want.

Comment: Please do not remove your question's content in this manner; it's not fair to those who already answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

try use this trick

```
If Apple = "" And Banana = "" Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND (1 = " + If (Inventory) <> 0 Then "1" else "0" + " AND (myApple = 0 AND myBanana = 0))"       
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND (1 = " + If (Inventory) <> -1 Then "1" else "0" + " AND(myApple <> 0 OR myBanana <> 0))"
End If
```

so get sqlwhere for Inventory = -1

```
AND (1 = 1 AND (myApple = 0 AND myBanana = 0)) AND (1 = 0 AND (myApple <> 0 OR myBanana <> 0))
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this doing?

Comment: u have 2 conditions that depends on value Inventory and isn't oposit. So if Inventory is 0 you can use only second conditions, if Inventory is -1 you can use only first condition and if Inventory is whaether else, u can use both conditions or nothing. So I choose use both condition in one sql query and add another condition 1=1 resp. 1=0. It is parametrized by Invenotry value.

Comment: I want to modify only the first condition...If inventory is -1 than use both condition.. Something like this : strSQL = strSQL & " AND (myApple = 0 AND myBanana = 0) + (myApple <> 0 OR myBanana <> 0)"